# Display multidimensional array in Smarty

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, smarty

This is my array.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [crop_id] => 34
        [group_id] => asd
        [crop_name] => dfg
        [varieties] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [crop_variety_id] => 43
                        [variety_name] => hjk
                        [stages] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [crop_id] => 34
                                        [stage_id] => 76
                                        [stage_name] => First Inspection
                                        [area] =>     --   
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [crop_id] => 34
                                        [stage_id] => 77
                                        [stage_name] => Vegetative Inspection
                                        [area] =>     --   
                                    )
```

I need to display **stage_name** from this array. I am using `{section}` loop from smarty.

I have my array of data in `$masterData`

```
{section name=i loop=$masterData}               
  {section name=j loop=$masterData[i].varieties}
    {section name=k loop=$masterData[j].stages}
        <th>{$masterData[i].varieties[j].stages[k].stage_name}</th>
    {/section}     
  {/section}
{/section}
```

This is giving me empty. How do i display stage_name from this multi dimensional array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss an imbrication `loop=$masterData[i].varieties[j].stages` instead of `loop=$masterData[j].stages`
try :

```
{section name=i loop=$masterData}               
    {section name=j loop=$masterData[i].varieties}
        {section name=k loop=$masterData[i].varieties[j].stages}
            <th>{$masterData[i].varieties[j].stages[k].stage_name}</th>
        {/section}     
    {/section}
{/section}
```